# how to post uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, post, file-upload, yii

I am trying to upload a file via simple form, then post it to my controller and move it to a certain directory in the server, but the file is not being posted, here is my code:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('jobs/view', array('id'=>$model->idJob)); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Phone Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Upload your CV</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cv" id="cv" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['fullName'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['phoneNumber'])){

                if ($_FILES["cv"]["error"] > 0) {
                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["cv"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }
                else {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["cv"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "Type: " . $_FILES["cv"]["type"] . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["cv"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
                }

                $uploaddir = getcwd()."/CVs/jobsApply/";
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['cv']['name'];

                echo '<pre>';
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cv']['name'], $uploadfile)) {
                    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
                } else {
                    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
                }
                $jobs = Jobs::model()->find('idJob='.$job);

                $to = 'jobs@site.com';

                $subject = 'Job Applying';

                $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['fullName']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Phone Number: ". strip_tags($_POST['phoneNumber']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "cv: ". strip_tags($_POST['cv']) . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                $url2 = $src."/CVs/jobsApply/".$model->fullName."-".$model->email."-".$model->cv;


                $message = '<html><body>';
                $message .= '<h3>'.$headers.'<br>Job reference: '.$jobs->reference.'</h3><br><h3>Candidate cv: <a href="site.com/CVs/jobsApply/'.$_POST['fullName']."-".$_POST['email']."-".$model->cv.'")Download CV</a></h3>';
                $message .= '</body></html>';
                $flgSend = @mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

so why I am not getting the file here?

Comment: Any type of error you are getting ?

Comment: @TBI there is no errors

Comment: You're missing one important and **crucial** element => `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I added it and I still have the problem

Comment: You are not getting post data ?

Comment: @TBI yes I am not getting it

Comment: In your controller, check using if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { print_r($_POST); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug it step by step

First check if the post values are even set:
Put a echo 'works'; or something like that below the if(isset($_POST['fullName'] etc line

If this works put a var_dump($_FILES);
See what you get out there

If theres an error in this array look up what it means here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Try this things see where it "stops working" before anyone can really help you any further i would say because theres kind of missing information here.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add this part to your form header: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It is required when posting binary data with your form, such as uploaded files. So your code's first line would look like:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('jobs/view', array('id'=>$model->idJob)); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form declaration.

See [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for that, and more useful information, on what you are trying to achieve.